# Java variable in XML

Tags: java, xml

I am working on a game, and for that I was creating a menu and it works all just fine for the most part. One thing, alle the assets are downloaded and stored in this folder

```
System.getProperty("user.home")+"/Library/Application Support/dragonfly"
```

because I'm on Mac. This works just fine. I have a method `getDirectory()` which returns that string. How do I get that variable in the xml file for the menu.

The library I'm working with needs it to be in a XML fo so because everything is downloaded and stored in that folder I have to set it there, but when I release the game it has to be compatible with every user name. So how do I get the `public String getDirectory()` in the XML file?

Comment: I am completely lost what you are trying to do or want it to do...

Comment: @Enerccio I try to get a Java Method in an XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step one. Invoke you getDirectory() method and remember result.

step two. put result to XML file.

Comment: so... how am I going to do that?

Comment: OKay, I got the trick. Thanks. I didn't realize Google is my best friend!